# How long did you wait for your Org Shape to be built?

Tags: salesforcedx, shape-org

```
sfdx force:org:shape:create -u master
```

I initiated the creation of **shape org** using the above command and I got the below message.

```
Successfully enqueued ShapeRepresentation creation for ID [ID here]
```

It has been 4 hours and the shape org is not created. If someone has created a shape org could you please tell me how long you waited? I am wondering if something is wrong OR I just need to wait longer.

Comment: `shape` is still in pilot till date so I think your best bet is to reach out to the group as mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/) for this topic or Salesforce support.

Comment: thanks for advice! will do that right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The force:org:shape:create command creates an org shape, not a shape org.  Creation is usually a pretty quick process, much faster than the creation of a sandbox org or scratch org because it's not creating an org.

In a sense, all the command does is create a virtual and online scratch org definition json file that you can then include in a real scratch org definition json file via that real file's top level "sourceOrg" attribute.  It is set to the org id of the org upon which the shape is based.  The sourceOrg attribute is used in the place of the "edition" attribute.  In general, your attribute values in your real file override any attribute values that would otherwise be taken from the org shape.

The command doesn't copy all the metadata or data.